# Register a receiver with many actions in manifest.xml

Tags: android, manifest

I want to register a receiver having many actions in Android manifest.xml.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL);
intentFilter.addDataScheme("package");
registerReceiver(installReceiver,intentFilter);
```

I am not able to figure it out. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try as:

```
<receiver android:name="getBroadcast" android:enabled="true" >   
  <intent-filter>   
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"></action>   
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED"></action>  
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"></action>  
    <data android:scheme="package"></data>   
  </intent-filter>   
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        <receiver
            android:name="your receiver class" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
                <!--more action-->
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: ok thanks, but how to add intentFilter.addDataScheme("package");?

Comment: add <data android:scheme=""/> in intent-filter tag

Answer (score 1):

Use `Intent-Filter` tag in manifest under `<reciever>`

```
<receiver android:name=".YourReciever">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
    <action android:name="your action3" />
</intent-filter>
</reciever>
```